# Error when saving a date column to the underlying database using sqlitedatadapter

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I would appreciate any help in finding why I get an error when saving back to a database. The error is: "Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records."
I have worked out that the error only occurs when my table has a date field which I fill from the underlying database use a sqlitedatadapter as follows:

```vb
Public connstring As String = "Data Source=c:\VS-2019\SaveTable\SaveTable\Data\TestDb.db"
Public conn As New SQLiteConnection

Public Sub FillMainTables()
    conn.ConnectionString = connstring
    conn.Open()
    DTAllCustomers.Rows.Clear()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM Customers"
    AllCustomersAdapter = New SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, conn)
    AllCustomersAdapter.Fill(DTAllCustomers)
End Sub
```

I then modify a few records in the datatable(DTAllCustomers) using this code

```vb
For i = 0 To DTAllCustomers.Rows.Count - 1
    If DTAllCustomers.Rows(i).Item("sitecode") = "RESI" Then
         DTAllCustomers.Rows(i).Item("Email") = "Changed"
    End If
Next
```

I then try to save the modified table back to the underlying database with:

```vb
Dim cbAllCustomers As New SQLiteCommandBuilder(AllCustomersAdapter)
AllCustomersAdapter.UpdateCommand = cbAllCustomers.GetUpdateCommand
Try
   AllCustomersAdapter.Update(DTAllCustomers)
Catch ex As Exception
   MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

When I remove the DATETIME columns in DTAllCustomers the error disappears and the update completes correctly.  Does SQLite change the date structure/value of the DateTime columns between filling the datatable and saving back to the datatable?

---

UpdateCommand.CommandText is:

```
UPDATE [main].[sqlite_default_schema].[Customers] SET [Email] = @param1 
    WHERE (([PrimaryKey] = @param2) 
    AND ([CustomerNumber] = @param3) 
    AND ((@param4 = 1 AND [Zone] IS NULL) OR ([Zone] = @param5)) 
    AND ((@param6 = 1 AND [SiteCode] IS NULL) OR ([SiteCode] = @param7)) 
    AND ((@param8 = 1 AND [FirstName] IS NULL) OR ([FirstName] = @param9)) 
    AND ((@param10 = 1 AND [Surname] IS NULL) OR ([Surname] = @param11)) 
    AND ((@param12 = 1 AND [Villa] IS NULL) OR ([Villa] = @param13)) 
    AND ((@param14 = 1 AND [Village] IS NULL) OR ([Village] = @param15)) 
    AND ((@param16 = 1 AND [Address] IS NULL) OR ([Address] = @param17)) 
    AND ((@param18 = 1 AND [Suburb] IS NULL) OR ([Suburb] = @param19)) 
    AND ((@param20 = 1 AND [PostCode] IS NULL) OR ([PostCode] = @param21)) 
    AND ((@param22 = 1 AND [Phone] IS NULL) OR ([Phone] = @param23)) 
    AND ((@param24 = 1 AND [Mobile1] IS NULL) OR ([Mobile1] = @param25)) 
    AND ((@param26 = 1 AND [Mobile2] IS NULL) OR ([Mobile2] = @param27)) 
    AND ((@param28 = 1 AND [Email] IS NULL) OR ([Email] = @param29)) 
    AND ((@param30 = 1 AND [System] IS NULL) OR ([System] = @param31)) 
    AND ((@param32 = 1 AND [Panels] IS NULL) OR ([Panels] = @param33)) 
    AND ((@param34 = 1 AND [Isolator] IS NULL) OR ([Isolator] = @param35)) 
    AND ((@param36 = 1 AND [Inverter] IS NULL) OR ([Inverter] = @param37)) 
    AND ((@param38 = 1 AND [SolarHotWater] IS NULL) OR ([SolarHotWater] = @param39)) 
    AND ((@param40 = 1 AND [Skylight] IS NULL) OR ([Skylight] = @param41)) 
    AND ((@param42 = 1 AND [Rebate] IS NULL) OR ([Rebate] = @param43)) 
    AND ((@param44 = 1 AND [Quote] IS NULL) OR ([Quote] = @param45)) 
    AND ((@param46 = 1 AND [Notes] IS NULL) OR ([Notes] = @param47)) 
    AND ((@param48 = 1 AND [LastCleaned] IS NULL) OR ([LastCleaned] = @param49)) 
    AND ((@param50 = 1 AND [BookedInDate] IS NULL) OR ([BookedInDate] = @param51)) 
    AND ((@param52 = 1 AND [BookedInOrder] IS NULL) OR ([BookedInOrder] = @param53)) 
    AND ((@param54 = 1 AND [Frequency] IS NULL) OR ([Frequency] = @param55)) 
    AND ((@param56 = 1 AND [NextCallDue] IS NULL) OR ([NextCallDue] = @param57)) 
    AND ((@param58 = 1 AND [Status] IS NULL) OR ([Status] = @param59)) 
    AND ((@param60 = 1 AND [Source] IS NULL) OR ([Source] = @param61)))
```

The parameter values and the date columns are in this format - #5/30/2018 12:00:00 AM#, however in the command text there is a @paramX = 1 for each column in the table and the paramX being passed has a value of 0.

Comment: Firstly, this line is useless: `AllCustomersAdapter.UpdateCommand = cbAllCustomers.GetUpdateCommand`.  If you're not going to modify the command you get, there's no point getting it.

Comment: I don't really use SQLite but it's my understanding that it doesn't have a specific date/time data type.  Are you saying that you are using a column with a data type of `DATETIME` or that you are using a column named "DATETIME" with, for instance, `TEXT` that is storing date/time data?

Comment: Please post the CommandText value of the UpdateCommand after creating the SQLiteCommandBuilder.  It would also be best to inspect data type of the command object's parameters.  This is important to see how it is enforcing concurrency.  SQLiteCommand object can properly store and retrieve dates using parameterized statements, but perhaps the CommandBuilder is not properly translating/interpreting the date representation.  You might need to write your update commands to do it properly.

Comment: Thanks CP I have looked at the parameter values and the date columns are in this format - #5/30/2018 12:00:00 AM#, however in the command text there is a @paramX = 1  for each column in the table and the paramX being passed has a value of 0.

Comment: @Brad  When replying to another user, make sure to use the proper markdown; otherwise the user will not be notified and may never see/respond to your comment.  Although it somewhat flexible, it will not recognize all abbreviations of the user name.  Click the help link next to the comment box for more info.

Comment: Look closer.  Notice that for each sub-expression that the `paramX` are NOT the same.  In particular for the [BookedInDate] column, `@param50 = 1` but later it has `([BookedInDate] = @param51)`.  `param50` is not the same as `param51`.  This query is for detecting concurrency problems (where one process updates the same row as another process).  `@param50` is only a flag value used when the original row value was NULL.  That's because it is not valid to compare NULL values using the `=`, so the query is built to compare either possibility.

Comment: It is also not useful to inspect the parameter value *before* the call to `AllCustomersAdapter.Update(DTAllCustomers)` since the Update command will set each parameter to the appropriate value for each row updated.  Don't get distracted by the value of `@param50`.  As I said before, instead start by inspecting the data type of the [BookedInDate] parameter.  This still is not the whole story, but can indicate some mix-up with data types.

Comment: Although there is not an actual DATETIME type in sqlite, built-in functions expect a format like "2018-05-30 12:00:00" (ISO-8601).  That's not required as long as you have consistent formatting, but eventually you'll have problems with database comparisons of dates in the format that you indicated.  You should investigate everywhere that data is inserted, that dates are being properly formatted.  Whatever the case, apparently you have different formats being generated that do not match, hence the concurrency errors.

Comment: @jmcilhinney jmc: I created the database using "SQLIte Expert Personal" which offers 3 options of date datatype DATE, DATETIME and DATETEXT. How that is truly stored I don't know.

Comment: @ C Perkins Thank you for the explanation of param50 I can see that now.  As I only open the database and fill the datatable then save the datatable having only changed the email column does this imply that sqlite is reading the date column when it fills the table then finds the format different when it tries to save it back?

Comment: @C Perkins   When I inspect the parameter value within the update command it shows the format as #5/30/2018 12:00:00 AM#  When I view the item value in the DataTable after it has been filled it is the same.